# $watch callback fires every time in browser but just once during the test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have code which should store information about filter changes.
In browser `$watch` callback fires every time I change value.
However, when I trying to replicate that in jasmine/karma test it fires just after first change.

Controller

```
var tableFilter = this
  ;

var init0 = true
  ;
$scope.$watch( 'tableFilter.config.period', function () {
  console.log('watch');
  if ( !init0 ) {
    console.log('set dirty');
    tbFilterConfig.set( 'pristine', false );
    tbFilterConfig.setDirty( 'period' );
  }
  init0 = false;
} );
```

Test

```
describe( '$scope $watch', function () {
  it( 'should add period to dirty after second change', function () {
    $scope.$apply(console.log(1), controller.config.period = 'test');
    expect( tbFilterConfigObj.get( 'dirty' ) ).toEqual( [] );
    $scope.$apply(console.log(2), controller.config.period = 'test2');
    expect( tbFilterConfigObj.get( 'dirty' ) ).toEqual( [ 'period' ] );
  } );
});
```

Output in console:

```
LOG: 1
LOG: 'watch'
LOG: 2
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Controller: TableFilterCtrl $scope $watch should add period to dirty after second change FAILED
Expected [  ] to equal [ 'period' ].
        at C:/Projects/trackback-network-insight-ui/test/spec/controllers/table_filter.js:74
```

But in browser:

```
setTimeout(function (  ) {
  $scope.$apply(console.log(1), tableFilter.config.period = 'test');
  $scope.$apply(console.log(2), tableFilter.config.period = 'test2');
}, 1000);
```

Gives me:

```
LOG: watch
LOG: 1
LOG: watch
LOG: set dirty
LOG: 2
LOG: watch
LOG: set dirty
```

That is expected behavior.

What is wrong with my test then? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Full controller code:

```
angular.module( 'insightApp' )
.controller( 'TableFilterCtrl', [ '$rootScope', 'tbConfig', '$scope', '$http', 'API_PATH', 'uiAlerts', 'tbFilterConfig',
  function ( $rootScope, tbConfig, $scope, $http, API_PATH, uiAlerts, tbFilterConfig ) {

    var tableFilter = this
      , newData = {}
      ;

    /* EXTRACT INITIAL DATA OR LOAD DATA IF TYPE OF DATA IS STRING */
    /* FETCH !!SELECT!! DATA FROM API */
    function fetchData( url, name ) {
      return $http.post( API_PATH + url, tbFilterConfig.get() )
        .success( function ( data ) {
          newData[ name ] = data;
        } )
        .error( function ( error ) {
          uiAlerts.set( {
            error: 'Ooops! We were unable to get filter data.'
          } );
          console.error( error );
        } );
    }

    tableFilter.filters = tbConfig.get( 'filters' );
    tableFilter.reports = tbConfig.get( 'reports' );
    tableFilter.config = tbFilterConfig.getRaw();

    /* RESET VALUES OF ALL DEPENDENT FILTERS */
    function resetDependent( name ) {
      var filters = tbConfig.get( 'filters' )
        ;
      filters.forEach( function ( filter ) {
        if ( filter.dependencies && filter.dependencies.indexOf( name ) > -1 ) {
          if ( tbFilterConfig.get( filter.key ) !== filter.defaultVal ) {
            tbFilterConfig.set( filter.key, filter.defaultVal );
            tbFilterConfig.setDirty( filter.key );
          }
        }
      } );
    }

    /* GET INITIAL DATA FOR SELECT OPTIONS */
    tableFilter.getData = function ( name, data, defaultVal ) {
      if ( !(name in newData) ) {
        newData[ name ] = [];
        if ( typeof data === 'string' ) {
          fetchData( data, name );
        } else if ( typeof data === 'object' ) {
          newData[ name ] = data;
        } else {
          console.error( 'Unexpected data type:', typeof data, data );
        }
        if ( !tbFilterConfig.get( name ) ) {
          tbFilterConfig.set( name, defaultVal );
        }
        var init = true;
        $scope.$watch( 'tableFilter.config.' + name, function () {
          if ( !init ) {
            resetDependent( name );
            tbFilterConfig.set( 'pristine', false );
            tbFilterConfig.setDirty( name );
          }
          init = false;
        } );
      }
      return newData[ name ];
    };

    /* WATCH FIXED PROPERTIES: PERIOD, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO */
    var init0 = true
      , init1 = true
      , init2 = true
      ;

    $scope.$watch( 'tableFilter.config.period', function () {
      if ( !init0 ) {
        tbFilterConfig.set( 'pristine', false );
        tbFilterConfig.setDirty( 'period' );
      }
      init0 = false;
    } );

    /* WATCH FIXED PROPERTIES DATE_FORM */
    $scope.$watch( 'tableFilter.config.date_from', function () {
      if ( !init1 ) {
        tbFilterConfig.set( 'pristine', false );
        tbFilterConfig.setDirty( 'date_from' );
      }
      init1 = false;
    } );
    /* WATCH FIXED PROPERTIES DATE_TO */
    $scope.$watch( 'tableFilter.config.date_to', function () {
      if ( !init2 ) {
        tbFilterConfig.set( 'pristine', false );
        tbFilterConfig.setDirty( 'date_to' );
      }
      init2 = false;
    } );

    /* UPDATE FILTER DATA */
    tableFilter.updateSelectData = function ( url, name, dependencies ) {
      if ( typeof url === 'string' ) {
        var touched = false;
        /* CHECK IF DEPENDENCIES CHANGED */
        for ( var i = 0; i < dependencies.length; i++ ) {
          if ( tableFilter.config.dirty.indexOf( dependencies[ i ] ) > -1 ) {
            touched = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        /* IF DEPENDENCIES CHANGED GET NEW DATA */
        if ( touched ) {
          return fetchData( url, name );
        }
      }
    };
  } ] );
```

and test:

```
describe( 'Controller: TableFilterCtrl', function () {

// load the controller's module

beforeEach( function () {
  module( 'insightApp' );
} );

var controller
  , $scope
  , alerts
  , tbFilterConfigObj
  ;

// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach( inject( function ( $controller, $rootScope, uiAlerts, tbFilterConfig ) {
  tbFilterConfigObj = tbFilterConfig;
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  alerts = uiAlerts;
  controller = $controller( 'TableFilterCtrl', {
    $scope: $scope
  } );
  $scope.$apply();
} ) );


describe( '$scope $watch', function () {
  it( 'should add period to dirty after second change', function () {
    $scope.$apply( console.log( 1 ), controller.config.period = 'test' );
    expect( tbFilterConfigObj.get( 'dirty' ) ).toEqual( [] );
    $scope.$apply( console.log( 2 ), controller.config.period = 'test2' );
    expect( tbFilterConfigObj.get( 'dirty' ) ).toEqual( [ 'period' ] );
  } );
} );
```

} );

**EDIT2**

I'm sorry for the code quality but it's not production yet.

Comment: wrap the second test with setTimeout(function() { expect( tbFilterConfigObj.get( 'dirty' ) ).toEqual( [ 'period' ] ); done(); }, 500); and don't forget to pass done parameter in the test.

Comment: @srinivasan how it suppose to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

When AngularJS runs in your browser, it runs `digest` cycles to trigger all watchers and their callbacks. This is what makes Angular work, and it happens automatically.

This mechanism doesn't work during unit tests. When running tests, you need to trigger the digest mechanism manually, by calling `$apply` or [`$digest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

Let's break down what happens in your test spec (which is displayed nicely in your console logs):

1. `$scope.$apply(console.log(1), controller.config.period = 'test');` -> writes `1` to console; changes the value of `config.period`.
2. `$scope.$apply(console.log(2), controller.config.period = 'test2');` -> triggers the watcher callback for `tableFilter.config.period` **for the first time** due to the `$apply`; writes `2` to console; changes the value of `config.period.`

Nothing is triggering the watcher's callback for the second time after that.

The solution is easy: add a call to `$scope.$digest()` (or `$scope.$apply()`) before each of your `expect` statements.

Comment: Doesn't `$scope.$apply(...);` trigger the digest after whatever is in parameters is evaluated? I think it does. Anyway I tried to add `$apply` to `beforeEach` as well as execute it after every change and it is not changing results of the test or console output.

Comment: can you try `$scope.$digest()` before every `expect` statement? If that doesn't work, please post your entire controller and test spec code

Comment: I tried and it doesn't change anything, because it already triggers `$digest` via `$apply` in exactly same way, I don't want to post that changes because it doesn't change anything from question perspective.

Comment: If you don't share your code, there's not a lot I can do to help

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your previous comment, I added code you requested.